# If statement is acting wrong

Tags: php, if-statement

```
    <div class ="content">
    <form action="" method="POST">

        <table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>Toilet:</td>
                <td><input placeholder="Toilet" type="text" name="Toilet"
                value="<?php isset ($_POST['Toilet'])?$_POST['Toilet']:"";?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Art. nr:</td>
                <td><input placeholder="Artikel nr." type="text" name="Artnr" 
                value ="<?php isset ($_POST['Artnr'])?$_POST['Artnr']:"";?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Art. nr fabrikant:</td>
                <td><input placeholder="Artikel nr. fabrikant" type="text" name="ArtNrFabrikant" 
                value ="<?php isset ($_POST['ArtNrFabrikant'])?$_POST['ArtNrFabrikant']:"";?>"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="AddToilet" value ="WC Toevoegen"/> <br />
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST ['AddToilet']))
            {
                if(!empty($_POST['Toilet'])&& !empty($_POST['Artnr'])&& !empty($_POST['ArtnrFabrikant']))
                {
                $result = $db->exec("INSERT INTO Toilet(Toilet, Artnr, ArtnrFabrikant) 
                VALUES('"
                .$_POST['Toilet']."','"
                .$_POST['Artnr']."','"
                .$_POST['ArtNrFabrikant'].
                "')");

                $insertId = $db->lastInsertId();
                echo "de ". $_POST['Toilet']. " is toegevoegd!";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Vul alles in<br />";  
                }
            }
        ?>
    </form>
    </div>
```

I got an issue with my IF statement :

```
if(!empty($_POST['Toilet']) && !empty($_POST['Artnr']) && !empty($_POST['ArtnrFabrikant']))
```

If I run this code it jumps to else, even when I filled in the 3 textfields.

When I remove the last part of the if statement:

```
 && !empty($_POST['ArtnrFabrikant']))
```

It goes into the if statement. So there is something wrong with my *ArtNrFabrikant*. But I don't know what's the problem.

Please help me out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: You have a typo in your form `ArtNrFabrikant`instead of `ArtnrFabrikant`.

Comment: Yea I see it now.. Programming all day is making a wreck of ur brains :P. I couldn't find the mistake.

Comment: So, instead of blaming a control structure, you learned that if something appears to be working bad or wrong - it's 99.99% your fault.

Comment: @N.B. Yep... Next time I'll just make the title: Find the typo :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a typo: one time the 'n' of 'nr' is capitalized and in the POST statement it's in lowercase

```
<input name="ArtNrFabrikant">

$_POST['ArtnrFabrikant'])
```

Comment: so the issue is solved then?

Answer (score 0):

You miscapitalized `ArtnrFabrikant`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST ['AddToilet']))
        {
            if(empty($_POST['Toilet'])&& empty($_POST['Artnr'])&& empty($_POST['ArtnrFabrikant']))
            {
                                echo "Vul alles in<br />";  
            }
            else
            {
                           echo "de ". $_POST['Toilet']. " is toegevoegd!";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Try this it works